# insert bulk statement - SQL 2005 - not "bulk insert"

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to look for the process/processes that is causing the transaction log to grow out of control. I have tried setting the DB to Bulk-Logged and it seems to still be growing. When set to Simple when the process/processes finish it clears. 
Profiler shows statements that start with "Insert Bulk xxxx" which I been reading about, but one thing I cannot determine is if "Insert Bulk" logs or not with the BULK-Logged setting.
Can anyone give me your thoughts on the "Insert Bulk" command

Answer (score 0):

Even in the bulk-logged recovery model, even with operations that are minimally logged,  you still need to take transaction log backups regularly - SQL Server still writes the allocation changes to the transaction log. How does the operation compare to when the database is in full recovery - in terms of speed, and transaction log backup sizes?

I'm sure you've read the pre-reqs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: While I do understand what is logged in BL I am trying to find out if insert bulk logs everything. I am looking for something that takes an empty 21GB log file and increases it to 60-70GB 99% used before it releases and goes back to 0% used.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the post.

http://sankarreddy.com/2011/03/interrogating-prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import-part-1/

If doesn't help then add more details and share the code snippets.